# EF Code First .SaveChanges Updating Wrong Table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have the following table declared

```
namespace RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities
{

    [Table( Name = "tblFixtures" )]
    [DisplayColumn( "Date", "Date", false )]
    public class Fixture
    {
        [HiddenInput( DisplayValue = false )]
        [Column( IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert )]
        public int FixtureID { get; set; }

        [Required( ErrorMessage = "Please select Male, Female or Mixed" )]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

    ...... more columns

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate( ValidationContext validationContext )
        {
            if (((ScoreFor > 0) || (ScoreAgainst > 0)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty( Comments )))
                yield return new ValidationResult( "Please complete either ScoreFor & ScoreAgainst or Comments!", new[] { "Comments" } );
        }
    }
}
```

My DbContext is as follows:

```
namespace RLSBCWebSite.Domain.Entities
{

    public class RLSBCWebSiteDb : DbContext

    {

        public DbSet<Officer> tblOfficers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Fixture> tblFixtures { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CompetitionWinner> tblCompetitionWinners { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My Web.Config has:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RLSBCWebSiteDb"
        connectionString="data source=MAINPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RLSBCWebSite;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My contoller code is:

```
        RLSBCWebSiteDb rlsbcWebSite = new RLSBCWebSiteDb();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateFixture(Fixture fixture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            rlsbcWebSite.tblFixtures.Add( fixture );
            rlsbcWebSite.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction( "MensResults", new { id = fixture.MatchDate.Year.ToString() } );
        }

        return View( fixture );
    }
```

When I try and save the entry, I get an SQL UpdateException with the following error message when the .SaveChanges() statement is executed.

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Fixtures'.

Why is it trying to update a table called Fixtures? Surely, it should be updating tblFixtures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `[Table( Name = "tblFixtures" )]` is invalid because `Name` isn't a property of the `TableAttribute` class - which looks like this:

```
public class TableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TableAttribute(string tableName);

    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; }
}
```

So, the following attribute settings should work both:

```
[Table("tblFixtures")]
```

or

```
[Table(TableName = "tblFixtures")]
```

**Edit**: But I am wondering now why you didn't get a compiler error?

I just noticed that there is another `TableAttribute` class in the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` namespace (in System.Data.Linq.dll assembly) which in fact has a `Name` property. Perhaps you have a wrong namespace-using. You need the `TableAttribute` class from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace (in EntityFramework.dll assembly).

Comment: @Slauma Thanks for your reply. This is the start of my table declarations

Comment: @Slauma Sorry about the last edit. I hit enter by mistake. Thanks anyway for you reply, but I am still at a loss. I have both ...DataAnnotations and ...Linq.Mapping declared in **using**. If I delete both references, Resolve only offers me ...Linq.Mapping for Table. TableAttribute does not appear to be a member of my ...DataAnnotations. You talk about ...DataAnnotations being in EntityFramework.dll, which I have in my **References** list. How would I add a reference to this version rather than the one I have included from in .NETFramework 4?

Comment: @xiecs: Are you using Entity Framework CTP5 for Code-First development? I mean the download from this page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d I am not sure if the TableAttribute was already available in CTP4. But the `EntityFramework.dll` which is included in the download I've linked contains definitely the TableAttribute in ...DataAnnotations namespace. I also would remove the `System.Data.Linq` assembly from your references (I think that's LINQ to SQL) unless you really need it for other purposes in your project.

Comment: @xiecs: I've just checked and compared the readme files for CTP4 and CTP5. And indeed `TableAttribute` is new in CTP5 and didn't exist in CTP4. Just check your version, EntityFramework.dll must be from December 2010.

Comment: @Slauma I have CTP5 installed. My EntityFramework.dll is dated 06/12/2010. But my ...DataAnnotations namespace still doesn't contain TableAttribute! Mine has a runtime version no of 4.0.30319. If that is wrong, I obviously need to update APSP.NET somehow; but I think I am on the latest as I have installed SP1 the other day. But could that have overwritten some later modules installed by EF4 CTP5 do you think?

Comment: @xiecs: That's crazy :( Version 4.0.30319 is correct. Just make another check: Go to the "References" node in solution explorer, open the node, right click on your "EntityFramework" reference, select "Show in Object Browser". Then the Object Browser displays all namespaces which are inside of the assembly. In `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` there you should see the `TableAttribute` class. If not, double check if you have really referenced the right EntityFramework.dll in your project and not accidentally an old one from somewhere else. Or delete the reference and create it again.

Comment: @Slauma: Looking at the Release Notes for CTP5, it talks about DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges replacing RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. If I make that change, it is not recognised so something is funny with my system!

Comment: @Slauma: I have checked Entity Framework as requested and ...DataAnnotations does indeed contain the TableAttribute class. The System.Entity.Data.Database namespace also contains the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges class I'm looking for. If I check ...DataAnnotations in my References in the same way you asked me to check EntityFramework.dll I do NOT see TableAttributes in the it. Is this therefore different to the copy enclosed in the EntityFramework.dll? If it is, how do I reference the correct version?

Comment: @xiecs: The `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly is not in conflict with EntityFramework.dll. The DataAnnotations namespace in EntityFramework.dll is an extension of the namespace in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll. (Namespaces are generally allowed to cross more than one assembly in .NET.) Do you have the old CTP4 version somewhere installed? It really looks that "somehow" your project references this old DLL, especially also because of your "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" problem. Try to rename or remove this old DLL just to see if your compiler is complaining.

Comment: @Slauma: The version number of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations I currently reference is the same as the Entity.Framework.dll 4.0.30319. That would suggest I have the latest version. I have however removed that reference and added it again. However, it still wants to use System.Data.Linq.Mapping to resolve Table.

Comment: @xiecs: I've just seen that 4.0.30319 is the runtime version of the .NET framework. All assemblies which are targeted for .NET 4 have this version (also EF CTP4 AND CTP5). So this version number does not really help us to distinguish. I believe the safest way to check the version is in "references"/right mouse click on "EntityFramework"/properties. Then check the "Path" in the properties window if it really points to that DLL with date 06/12/2010.

Comment: @Slauma: Part of the path in which Entity Framework.dll is stored says /Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Feature CTP5/, so I am assuming that I am referencing the correct version. Just a thought, if the TableAttribute class exists in both the ...DataAnnotations and the ...Linq.Mapping namespaces, how does it know which to offer when you use mouse button 2 and select Resolve? It is only showing me ...Linq.Mapping.

Comment: @Slauma: Here's an interesting development. If I click the word Table and then move the arrow cursor off it, a box appears which says 'Initiates a new instance of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayColumnAttributes class'. But it is still underlined in red because it wants 'using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;' to be present, which I have removed temporarily. When I replace it, it then complains about TableName, so it is definitely using ...Linq.Mapping and not ...DataAnnotations.

Comment: @xiecs: If you select "Resolve" the IDE offers ALL namespaces it can find in the referenced assemblies for the particular class. So in your case it should offer "System.Data.Linq.Mapping" AND "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations". The fact that you get "...DataAnnotions" offered indicates that the compiler doesn't recognize the EntityFramework.dll somehow. Really, really strange thing.

Comment: @xiecs: But I still have the feeling that you have somewhere a reference to the old CTP4 version (or even older), because: "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" and "TableAttribute" doesn't work (new features from CTP5) but "DbSet" and "DbContext" and so on works (features from CTP4 and CTP5). Do you have somewhere an old CTP4 installation on your harddrive? Can you remove or rename it?

Comment: @Slauma: I think I have solved it. I had a reference to Microsoft.Data.Entity.CTP still in the list. This is a CTP4 reference. I have removed it and now I get both namespaces when I select "Resolve". I can't thank you enough for your very patient help. Working at home alone trying to learn a new technology is not easy, particularly one that is changing so quickly. I do miss the office environment with someone sitting next to you who you can chew things over with. It is only sites like this and the many helpful people that keeps me sane. Do I flag your original answer as "the answer"?

Comment: @xiecs: Wow, I'm glad that you found the reason for the issue now! BTW: Since yesterday the release candidate for EF Code-First is available (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx). It might be worth to consider to upgrade since it's likely that a lot of bugs in CTP5 have been fixed (and also some new features have been added). I probably will also update within the next days. (Marking the original answer is fine, finally the main reason was the wrong namespace.) Good luck with your evolving project now!

Comment: @Slauma: I've just installed EF Code First RC4.1 and it is still causing me problems. I have a [Table( ...] spec on a class defining the columns of a table. On the PK column, I have a [Column( ...] spec. I need ...DataAnnotations to manage the [Table and ...Linq.Mapping to handle the [Column. Because both have a TableAttribute and ColumnAttribute, whichever one I set, the namespace automatically tries to handle the other, if you see what I mean. I cannot set one namespace to handle the one attribute and the other namespace to handle the other. Any suggestions?

Comment: @xiecs: Are you really sure that you need the `ColumnAttribute` from the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` namespace? This namespace contains the classes used for `LINQ to SQL` which is another technology for DataAccess than EntityFramework. It's very, very uncommon to mix both technologies in one application (and it also might cause a lot of conflicts). Do you really want to use `LINQ to SQL` AND EntityFramework together?

Comment: @xiecs: Generally if you have such a class name conflict you can resolve it by fully qualifying the class name like so: `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Table(...)]` and `[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(...)]`. (But as said, double check first, if `Column` from `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` is really what you want. The `Column` attribute of EF4 Code-First is definitely that from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Comment: @Slauma: 'Column' used to be in ...LInq.Mapping. It gave parameters such as 'IsPrimaryKey' and 'IsDbGenerated'. All you need now apparently is '[Key]' in ...DataAnnotations. Once again, thank you so much for your help. I will spend some time going through the EF 4.1 education. Let's consider this question closed.